# Building a File Explorer on Android 11

Tags: android, mediastore, android-storage, android-11

I'm looking forward to build a File Explorer app but I'm shocked with what I found on I do need full read/write permission and access to everything.

So as they state [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files):

> Declare the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest.

> Use the ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION intent action to direct users to a system settings page where they can enable the following option for your app

> To determine whether your app has been granted the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, call Environment.isExternalStorageManager().

Now I can access to the root folder "*/storage/emulated/0/*" via `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(path)` and then `file.listFiles()`

But when I want to access to Downloads folder I can't, I've looked at SAF but I'd have to use like ACTIONS and I just want to explore through folders, then I looked at MediaStore but there's not a clear example of how I could use it here since I'm trying to get the files but `cursor.moveToNext()` or `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false

Here's the code I've used

```
val projectionDownloads = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Downloads._ID,
    MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME,
  )
val selectionDownloads = ""
val selectionArgsDownloads = emptyArray<String>()
val sortOrderDownloads = "${MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME} ASC"

context.applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projectionDownloads,
    selectionDownloads,
    selectionArgsDownloads,
    sortOrderDownloads
  )?.use { cursor ->
        Log.i("SeeMedia", "we got cursor! $cursor")
        val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID)
        val nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { //Here return false
            Log.i("SeeMedia", "Move to next!")
            val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
            val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
            Log.i("SeeMedia", "ID = $id AND NAME= $name")
        }
    }
```

My app contains the 2 permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

***There are 3 questions that I'm wondering after this:***

Question 1: Do I need other permissions for the purpose of reading files?

Question 2: What am I missing on this MediaStore query? Why it doesn't provide me the files of download?

Question 3: What if I want to query on other unknown files/directories, for example a folder inside Downloads which there is another folder and so on? "*Downloads/Folder1/Folder2*" ***I guess I should use MediaStore.Files, right? So how is the URI for accessing those files?***

**EDIT 1:**
SDK 29 = Android 10

SDK 30 = Android 11

What I want is to query are just files, no image, no audio just files whatever it comes, so for example the path "/" which is root will return a list of Directories:
-Ringtones
-Music
-DCIM
-Download
-Documents

That's good it works with the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory and the permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

But then I want to access to one of those directories and it's empty, for example "DCIM" (which I know it contains some pictures) and <= 28 it retrieves me the pictures with:

- Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()/DCIM

But in >= 29 it returns an empty, how could I get access to those files with the classic methods or MediaStore?

If I'm wrong in something just tell me because right now my head is filled with a lot of mixed stuff since I've watched a lot of videos and documentation and questions and I'm just trying to understand some critical points.

Here's a simple code that I finally could query the root "/" with MediaStore in case you want to see it, but don't know how to query other paths and retrieve me their files:

```
val projection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
  )
context.applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    null
  )?.use { cursor ->
        Log.i("SeeMedia", "we got cursor! $cursor")
        val nameColumn = 
        cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Log.i("SeeMedia", "Move to next!")
            val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
            Log.i("SeeMedia", "Name = $name")
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Now I can access to the root folder "/storage/emulated/0/" via Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(path)`. No. You have to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() for that.

Comment: `when I want to access to Downloads folder I can't` Well you can. You are doing something wrong then.

Comment: `, I've looked at SAF but I'd have to use like ACTIONS` You can make a SAF-Explorer too. You only need to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE for every partition once.

Comment: Hey thank you for answering! I changed to getExternalStorageDirectory() as you pointed out which returns the same `/storage/emulated/0/` and works perfectly for getting the root.

Comment: About SAF explorer, that is not what I'm looking into since I want to list every directory I find and not certain partitions. So I guess MediaStore is the API to go in my case, right?

Comment: No. If you have all files access you can use classic File methods to browse all folders.

Comment: And for SAF: once you have permission obtained for a partition you can browse all folders of it. Most devices have two partitions. Pixel devices have only one.

Comment: I'm using the classic File methods below api 30 and I find the "Download" files but on API 30 returns an empty list `File("${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/Download").listFiles().toList()` Am I missing something?

Comment: So what you're telling me about SAF is that I can access to all folders even folders created by the user, for example I create a folder named "myNewFolder" and with SAF i can access there?

Comment: `but on API 30 returns an empty list` Yes, on an Android 10 device. And No, as list() returns `null`But your question was about Android 11 -devices-.

Comment: `I create a folder named "myNewFolder" and with SAF i can access there?` It is unclear where you wanna create that folder exactly. But.. if you can create it you have access.

Comment: Hey I don't want to make this discussion longer, we can continue on chat where I have explained it much better and with more in details so we can solve this real quick if you want and have enough time of course! [Here's the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226322/discussion-between-barrufet-and-blackapps)

Comment: Sorry, this is a forum. No chat room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering some of your questions:

> Do I need other permissions for the purpose of reading files?

No, as it's stated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#permissions), you've got all the possible file-related permissions.

> What am I missing on this MediaStore query? Why it doesn't provide me the files of download?

Download is a kind of special case. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#scoped_storage_enabled) at the very bottom of the section it says

> In particular, if your app wants to access a file within the
> MediaStore.Downloads collection that your app didn't create, you must
> use the Storage Access Framework.

And even using SAF you [will not be able to access](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions) all files in Download directory. So you can access a single file picked by user, but you cannot list the content of the directory.

Generally, as it's stated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#operations-allowed-manage-external-storage), having the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission granted, you can access all non-restricted files using both `MediaStore` and [file paths](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths). Both ways should give the same result.

Comment: It's been solved, it was working all this time but I had no files on Downloads because this was a new API and I had not downloaded anything and on my other sdk 24 I had files so I completely forgot to check that, I'm so retarded but thank you for answering my questions! File paths are working on sdk 30 :)